# Expert System (Technical Diagnosis)

Tags: diagnostics, expert-system

I'm currently supporting a small part of software which is really error prone. There are a lot of things people can do wrong while installation and so on.

So now i remembered things called "expert systems" we played around with in school. So the program asked you questions and leads you to the solution of your problem. I'd really like to make such a system and searched for solutions on the internet.

But i couldn't find a program to create such expert systems.

Do you have any suggestions or do i really have to program it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4175154/744588) question and its related answers on SO.

Personnaly, I prefer a [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) based solution due to early exposure to [Turbo Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Prolog) back in 1987:

- I was impressed by a small medical Expert System carrying out a differential diagnosis.